# Model averaging with MuMIn: interpretation of coefficient-names in results

Tags: r, inference, coefficients, mumin

I am doing model averaging with MuMIn and trying to interpret the results.
Everything works fine, but I am wondering about the **names of my coefficients** in the results:

```
Model-averaged coefficients:  
(full average) 
                     Estimate Std. Error Adjusted SE
cond((Int))         0.9552775  0.0967964   0.0969705
cond(Distanzpunkt) -0.0001217  0.0001451   0.0001453
cond(area_km2)      0.0022712  0.0030379   0.0030422
cond(prop)          0.0487036  0.1058994   0.1060808
```

Does someone know, what "**cond()**" tells me and why it appears in the model output?

Within the models, the coefficients are named "Distanzpunkt", "area_km2" and "prop".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you fitting a zero inflation model with `glmmTMB`? If so, then cond() is referring to the terms in the conditional model, rather than the zero-inflation model.